# What is the Big O notation of a loop in loop

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, big-o

I have this code and cannot understand the Big-O of this... Thanks

```
for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
  for(j = i; j<n; j++){
    if (arr[j]%2!=0){
       if (minodd > arr[j]){
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if there is an operation inside the inner `for`, how many time would it execute in terms of n?

Comment: Inside of the last loop is a if

Comment: `n+(n-1)+(n-2)+... = `?

Comment: Is O(n^2) -1???? I cant understand.

Comment: yes. See my answer for detailed explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best ways to approach this problem is to break it down into smaller parts.

First, lets look at your inner loop:

```c
for(j = i; j<n; j++){
    if (arr[j]%2!=0){    // O(1)
       if (minodd > arr[j]){ // O(1)
       }
    }
  }
```

The if-statements are O(1) or constant time so we can ignore those and we get just the inner for loop:

```c
for(j = i; j<n; j++){
... // O(1) + O(1)
}
```

Since the worst case scenario is it loops n times we have `O(n) + O(1) + O(1)` which can be simplified to `O(n)` which is called **linear time**.

Next, lets zoom out and replace the inner loop with our new info:

```c
for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
  for(j = i; j<n; j++){
    if (arr[j]%2!=0){
       if (minodd > arr[j]){
       }
    }
  }
}
```

becomes:

```c
for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
    O(n)
}
```

Since we know the outside for loop will cycle n times in the worst case, and the inside for loop will cycle n times in the worst case: We get O(n x n) or **`O(n²)`** which is also know as **polynomial time**.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Doesn't this just go on for forever?</strike>

You have `i < n` in your inner loop, so I think it's `O(inf)`.

Now that you've updated the loop, I think @e2-e4 is right:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int eqn(int n)
{
    return n > 0 ? n + eqn(n - 1) : 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, j, n, v, a;

    v = 0;
    n = 5;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
            v++;
        }
    }

    // v = 15 ? 15
    printf("v = %d ? %d\n", v, eqn(n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: n is a number, for example 10, and i is increasing by 1